# d3 - load two specific columns from csv file

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am trying to plot circles on a map based on data from csv files. I want the latitude and longitude from the csv file and plot a circle. 
I am unable to long the two fields. I get an object undefined error. Here's my code so far:
Here's the link for the CSV file -
http://slate-interactives-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com/gun-deaths/getCSV.php

```
 <html>
                <head>
         <meta    charset="utf-8">
        <link href="d3-geomap/css/d3.geomap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="d3-geomap/vendor/d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js"></script>
        <script src="d3-geomap/js/d3.geomap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
    path.unit:hover{
    fill:#99d8c9;
}
</style>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
    </html>

   <script>
    var map = d3.geomap.choropleth()
    .geofile('d3-geomap/topojson/countries/USA.json')
    .projection(d3.geo.albersUsa)
    .column('2012')
    .unitId('fips')
    .scale(1000)
    .legend(true);

    var width = 950,
    height = 550;

// set projection
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();

// create path variable
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);

    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    var coordinates = projection([data.lat,data.lng]);
    svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", coordinates[0])
            .attr("cy", coordinates[1])
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", "red");
    });

    d3.select('#map')
        .call(map.draw, map);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of problems in your code. First the `data` object that `d3.csv` retrieves is an array. It's the elements of that array that will have properties such as `.lat` and `.lng`. So `data.lat` and `data.lng` are not defined.

I'm guessing that you want to create circles for each element in the array. You could do that by iterating through the array, e.g.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    var coordinates = projection([d.lat, d.lng]);
    // ...
});
```

That's not the normal D3 idiom (it's not using selections and `.enter()`) but it would work.

Secondly, CSV files are always read as text strings, even when the values are actually numbers. You'll want to convert from strings to numbers, so the code above really should be

```
    var coordinates = projection([parseFloat(d.lat), parseFloat(d.lng)]);
```

As I said, there may be other problems with your code, but fixing those two should at least get you further along.