# D3 Loading in CSV file then using only specific columns

Tags: csv, d3.js

I've had a hard time getting two columns from a CSV file with which I am planning on building a basic bar chart. I was planning on getting 2 arrays (one for each column) within one array that I would use as such to build a bar chart. Just getting started with D3, as you can tell.

Currently loading the data in gets me an array of objects, which is then a mess to get two columns of key-value pairs. I'm not sure my thinking is correct...

I see this similar question:

[d3 - load two specific columns from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381347/d3-load-two-specific-columns-from-csv-file)

But how would I use selections and enter() to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why don't you simply map each property?

Comment: can you share some code of what you have tried so far? Keep in mind that you can manipulate the data structure before feeding it to d3, if that makes it easier to handle while drawing the visualisation

Answer (score 9):

You can't load just 2 columns of a bigger CSV, but you can load the whole thing and extract the columns you want.

Say your csv is like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
aaa1,aaa2,aaa3,aaa4
bbb1,bbb2,bbb3,bbb4
ccc1,ccc2,ccc3,ccc4
```

And you load it with

```
csv('my.csv', function(err, data) {
  console.log(data)
  /*
    output:
    [
      { col1:'aaa1', col2:'aaa2', col3:'aaa3', col4:'aaa4' },
      { col1:'bbb1', col2:'bbb2', col3:'bbb3', col4:'bbb4' },
      { col1:'ccc1', col2:'ccc2', col3:'ccc3', col4:'ccc4' }
    ]
  */
})
```

If you only want `col2` and `col3` (and you don't want to simply leave the other columns' data in there, which shouldn't be an issue anyway), you can do this:

```
var cols2and3 = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    col2: d.col2,
    col3: d.col3
  }
});

console.log(cols2and3)
/*
  output:
  [
    { col2:'aaa2', col3:'aaa3' },
    { col2:'bbb2', col3:'bbb3' },
    { col2:'ccc2', col3:'ccc3' }
  ]
*/
```

I.e. the above code produced a new array of objects with only two props per object.

If you want just an array of values per column — not objects with both columns' values — you can:

```
var col2data = data.map(function(d) { return d.col2 }
var col3data = data.map(function(d) { return d.col3 }

console.log(col2) // outputs: ['aaa2', 'bbb2', 'ccc2']
```